# Имя пакета с gcc в Nexenta

Tags: apt-get, unix, solaris, gcc, linux

Задаю вопрос здесь, а не на Руткоде, потому что здесь больше пользователей и большая вероятность ответа, а соотвествующие вопросы на Руткоде уже задал и пока что не получил ответа(http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/5794/linux-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-nexenta). 
В связи с вопросом на http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/5776/linux-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-gcc-%D0%B2-nexenta , другой руководитель посоетовал удалить gcc через apt. Но на команду

```
apt-get --purge remove gcc
```

выдает следующее:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package gcc is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++6-4.2-dev : Depends: g++-4.2 (= 4.2.3-2nexenta7) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: gcc-4.2-base (= 4.2.3-2nexenta7) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.3-2nexenta7) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Из этих сообщений

```
Package gcc is not installed, so not removed
```

следует, что пакет с gcc называется по другому. При этом gcc действительно установлен и в ответ на

```
gcc -v
```

выдает

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i386-pc-solaris2.11
Configured with: ../src/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr/gcc/4.4 --enable-shared --with-system-zlib --with-gmp-include=/usr/include/gmp --with-gmp-lib=/usr/lib --with-mpfr-include=/usr/include/mpfr --with-mpfr-lib=/usr/lib --with-as=/usr/sfw/bin/gas --with-gnu-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/ld --without-gnu-ld --enable-libstdcxx-allocator=mt --enable-nls --enable-objc-gc --enable-libssp --libexecdir=/usr/gcc/4.4/lib --enable-c99 --with-pic --enable-wchar_t --mandir=/usr/gcc/4.4/share/man --infodir=/usr/gcc/4.4/share/info --build=i386-pc-solaris2.11
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.4 (GCC)
```

Как узнать имя этого пакета?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@ivan31](/users/4705/ivan31)

```
 dpkg -S `which gcc`
```

Comment: @ivan31 developer-gcc, да ещё 44 -- это круто (Шютка)